# Change names in a function in R

Tags: r, function

I can use the following code to change the name in the cells in my data.frame:

```
df$column <- gsub("Old name", "New name", df$column)
```

However, I want to create it as a function. I have tried with the following, but it does not work:

```
changename <- function(data) {
  data$column <- gsub("Old name", "New name", data$column)
}

changename(df)
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Add `return(data)` in function?

Comment: `R` is call-by-value, that means that by calling your function, the operations in your function are performed on a local copy and not the original object

Comment: Of course. My mistake. Thanks for your answer. :-)